# Smooth heatmap - how to create them?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to create 'smooth' heatmap in R. At the moment I can get the basic one with bins or hexagons based on the example I found in web:

```
# Color:
rf <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
r <- rf(32)

# Data:
x <- rnorm(mean=1.5, 5000)
y <- rnorm(mean=1.6, 5000)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

#Plot:
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))
h3 <- p + stat_bin_hex(bins=25) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=r)
h3
```

[image]

I'd prefer something like an example below. It's only about visual aspect. Have you got any idea how to create something roughly similar?

[image]

Comment: What about stat_density_2d ?

Comment: If your data had higher resolution (i.e. more data points per inch²'), this would automatically make your graph smoother. If you want smoothness in the absence of high-resolution data, you would have to "fill in the blanks", for example by interpolating your data to a higher resolution and then applying some filter to smooth it out.

Comment: theoretically, you are talking about smaller pixels, what about using the ggplot hex bin with more bins? you can also see the solutions provided by [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/), the solution provided [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay) with base(!) graphics and ggplot or the solution provided [here](http://www.everydayanalytics.ca/2014/09/5-ways-to-do-2d-histograms-in-r.html) using `MASS`'s `kde2d` function.

Comment: But for example [here](https://www.hoverowl.com/assets-site/images/tour/heatmap-hover.jpg) single points look like a quite big, blurry circles (top right corner) colliding with each other and eventually creating smooth heatmap. Can I somehow do it in a similar way?

Comment: Use `p + stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = 'raster', contour = FALSE, n = 500) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=r)`, as @MrSmithGoesToWashington suggested. (I would preferably use a `viridis` color scale to avoid the banding though.) Also, that plot is not `h3` since it doesn't have hex bins.

Comment: @Axeman That looks really nice, thank you! But I have additional, final question. Is there a possibility to draw this only in the areas where the points exist? In other words - make dark background transparent?

Comment: You can set a lower cut-off for the fill scale, e.g. `scale_fill_gradientn(colours=r, limits = c(0.01, 0.18), na.value = NA)`.

Answer (score 2):

how about you make it as a contour?

```
library("ash")
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
xmax=max(df$x)
xmin=min(df$x)
xstep=(xmax-xmin)/25
xlevels=as.numeric(levels(cut(df$x,25,labels=seq(xmin,xmax,xstep)[-1])))
ymax=max(df$y)
ymin=min(df$y)
ystep=(ymax-ymin)/25
ylevels=as.numeric(levels(cut(df$y,25,labels=seq(ymin,ymax,ystep)[-1])))

x00<-bin2(x=as.matrix(df),nbin=c(25,25))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
filled.contour(x00$nc, color.palette = my_palette,main = "My Contour",x=xlevels,y=ylevels)
```

[image]

Comment: I can go to bed now, thanks a lot!